# Partitioning data for a timestamp query

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have paritioned data on s3 I would like to access via spectrum.  The current format file structure is similar to: `s3://bucket/dir/year=2018/month=11/day=19/hour=12/file.parquet`

I partitioned the data using glue, by parsing a field I use for timestamps, `ts`.  Most queries I will do will be on the `ts` field, as they are timestamp range queries that are more granular than daily(may span multiple days, or less than one day, but time is often involved.

How would I go about creating hourly(preferred, daily would work if needed) partitions on my data so when I query the `ts`(or another timestamp) field, it will access the partitions correctly.  If needed I can recreate my data with different paritions.  Most examples/docs just bucket data daily, and use the date field in the query.

I would be happy to provide more information if needed.

Thank you!

Example query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM spectrum.data
WHERE ts between '2018-11-19 17:30:00' AND '2018-11-20 04:45:00'
```

Comment: please share your example query?

Comment: Updated the original post, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I got into similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Spectrum is not so intuitive. You probably will need to convert timestamp to year, month, day ...

And than do something like WHERE (year > x AND year < y) AND (month > x1 AND month < x2) AND ...

Looks ugly.

You can consider doing something else :

1. s3://bucket/dir/date=2018-11-19/time=17:30:00/file.parquet

In that case your query will be more simple

WHERE ( date < '2018-11-19' AND date > '2018-11-17') AND ( time < '17:30:00' AND time > '17:20:00')

OR using BETWEEN
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_range_condition.html

Comment: Is there anything better now? As we moved more than 3 years. I got stuck at same issue

Answer (score 1):

If the partitions are created like mentioned below, it will cater to the query asked by @Eumcoz

```
ALTER TABLE spectrum.data ADD PARTITION (ts='2018-11-19 17:30:00') 
LOCATION 's3path/ts=2018-11-19 17:30:00/';
ALTER TABLE spectrum.data ADD PARTITION (ts='2018-11-19 17:40:00') 
LOCATION 's3path/ts=2018-11-19 17:40:00/';
ALTER TABLE spectrum.data ADD PARTITION (ts='2018-11-19 17:50:00') 
LOCATION 's3path/ts=2018-11-19 17:50:00/';
ALTER TABLE spectrum.data ADD PARTITION (ts='2018-11-20 07:30:00') 
LOCATION 's3path/ts=2018-11-20 07:30:00/';
```

Then if you fire this query, it will return the data in all the above partitions:

```
select * from spectrum.data where ts between '2018-11-19 17:30:00' and '2018-11-20 07:50:00'
```

P.S. Please up-vote this if it solves your purpose. (I need 50 reputations to be able to comment on posts :) )